# How to implement eloquent events in laravel using commmon Trait for all models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using **laravel 5.4** to create a web app.

I have created a trait to implement events for created, updated, deleted and restored eloquent events.

I have created a **trait** as below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Auth;
use App\Master\Activity;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

/**
 * Class ModelEventLogger
 * @package App\Traits
 *
 *  Automatically Log Add, Update, Delete events of Model.
 */
trait ActivityLogger {

    /**
     * Automatically boot with Model, and register Events handler.
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {   
        parent::boot();
        foreach (static::getRecordActivityEvents() as $eventName) {
            static::$eventName(function (Model $model) use ($eventName) {
                try {
                    $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($model);
                    return Activity::create([
                        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                        'content_id' => $model->id,
                        'content_type' => get_class($model),
                        'action' => static::getActionName($eventName),
                        'description' => ucfirst($eventName) . " a " . $reflect->getShortName(),
                        'details' => json_encode($model->getDirty()),
                        'ip_address' => Request::ip()
                    ]);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    Log::debug($e->getMessage());//return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the default events to be recorded if the $recordEvents
     * property does not exist on the model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected static function getRecordActivityEvents()
    {
        if (isset(static::$recordEvents)) {
            return static::$recordEvents;
        }

        return [
            'created',
            'updated',
            'deleted',
            'restored'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Return Suitable action name for Supplied Event
     *
     * @param $event
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getActionName($event)
    {
        switch (strtolower($event)) {
            case 'created':
                return 'create';
                break;
            case 'updated':
                return 'update';
                break;
            case 'deleted':
                return 'delete';
                break;
            case 'restored':
                return 'restore';
                break;
            default:
                return 'unknown';
        }
    }
}
```

But when I am implementing it in my **Model** like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Master;

use App\Traits\ActivityLogger;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class LeadSource extends Model
{
    use ActivityLogger;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'lead_source';
    protected $primaryKey = 'lead_source_id';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'created_by', 'created_ip', 'updated_by', 'updated_ip'
    ];
}
```

Then in my **controller** i am calling created/update as usual via eloquent model. But the events aren't fired up and not recording anything in the activity table.

Below is my **Migration** for activity table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateActivityTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('activity', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('activity_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('content_id');
            $table->string('content_type', 255);
            $table->string('action', 255);
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->longText('details')->nullable();
            $table->ipAddress('ip_address')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('activity');
    }
}
```

Please advise what is the issue?

Comment: I think you need to name your function `bootActivityLogger` instead of `boot` which may cause issues or not be taken into account at all (since Model already has a boot method).

Comment: @apokryfos I tried that as well, still it is not recording anything in the db. And I think it can work with `boot` as well because I had added `parent::boot();` to include Model's boot method.

Comment: @apokryfos Is correct. If you want to use the boot method from a trait you need to name is like so `'boot'.class_basename($trait))` which would be `protected static function bootActivityLogger() `. That being said have a look at: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog

Comment: @RossWilson keeping the name as `boot()` and then adding this `parent:boot();` inside the function will also work and do the same thing I guess. I think both are same just different way of doing. But I will go with this `protected static function bootActivityLogger()` as you advised,

Comment: Yeah, it's mainly for when you have a `boot()` method in a model that is also using a trait with a `boot()` method. The trait's `boot()` method will be ignored in favour of the model's. It should be a fairly easy refactor though if you were to go down that route :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, all ok with Model and Migration, it was the trait where it was making issue. There were a no. of things wrong and which was preventing it to work properly.

And the most important thing which was wrong is the Log, I did;t included proper class for it and that caused the issue.

Here is the corrected code for the trait file only.

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Auth;
use Request;
use App\Master\Activity;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

/**
 * Class ModelEventLogger
 * @package App\Traits
 *
 *  Automatically Log Add, Update, Delete events of Model.
 */
trait ActivityLogger {

    /**
     * Automatically boot with Model, and register Events handler.
     */
    protected static function bootActivityLogger()
    {   
        foreach (static::getRecordActivityEvents() as $eventName) {
            static::$eventName(function ($model) use ($eventName) {
                try {
                    $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($model);
                    return Activity::create([
                        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                        'content_id' => $model->attributes[$model->primaryKey],
                        'content_type' => get_class($model),
                        'action' => static::getActionName($eventName),
                        'description' => ucfirst($eventName) . " a " . $reflect->getShortName(),
                        'details' => json_encode($model->getDirty()),
                        'ip_address' => Request::ip()
                    ]);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    Log::debug($e->getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the default events to be recorded if the $recordEvents
     * property does not exist on the model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected static function getRecordActivityEvents()
    {
        if (isset(static::$recordEvents)) {
            return static::$recordEvents;
        }

        return [
            'created',
            'updated',
            'deleted',
            'restored'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Return Suitable action name for Supplied Event
     *
     * @param $event
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getActionName($event)
    {
        switch (strtolower($event)) {
            case 'created':
                return 'create';
                break;
            case 'updated':
                return 'update';
                break;
            case 'deleted':
                return 'delete';
                break;
            case 'restored':
                return 'restore';
                break;
            default:
                return 'unknown';
        }
    }
}
```

Please check and advise if anything wrong or could be done in better way.

Comment: Another option is to extend Model, implement your classes in that child-class and then extend your models again with that child-class.

Comment: @ThomasMoors In that case I need to go and add that extend class whenever I will create any model? or I can create duplicate Model class, just like Controller ?

Comment: just a child: `MyModel extends Model` `ModalA extends MyModel` and `ModalB extends MyModel` also